# Symfony Entity property of text with length behavior

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Perhaps this behavior is a bug or my own ignorance but I just came across this and hoping someone has some insight.

I was recently adding a property to an existing entity called `notes` for which I wanted a text property (not a string with a length) because of the unknown amount of data that would go into it.  I got lazy and copied the existing title property in the entity, changed the name and table mapping to 'notes', but forgot to remove the `length` property in the annotation, so I ended up with this...

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="notes", type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $notes;
```

I updated schema and started to populate `notes` on existing entities and noticed that they were being truncated, realized my mistake, removed the length property, cleared the metadata cache, and went to update the schema to which I received:

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Sure enough, I no longer have a length property in my entity, but `notes` are still being truncated.

Upon inspecting the table I realize that the `notes` column is **TINYTEXT**, so that would be the problem.  I manually change it to **LONGTEXT** and problem solved.

**So my question is:**

Why would running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` (even after clearing doctrine's metadata cache) not alter the column to LONGTEXT from TINYTEXT in the absence of the length property?

Is this an oversite in Doctrine or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at [the documentation](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/types.html#id85) you can see that if you do not specify a `length` it will default to `255`.

The documentation also states [here](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/types.html#id102) that if the `length` is `<= 255` it will use the type `TINYTEXT`.

Comment: That applies to `string` and `binary` types, not `text`.  If you click the associated reference numbrers [1,2] in the documentation next to that line, you'll see where they apply.  Also this:  http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/types.html#text

Comment: I do realize what you're saying, but the question is why doesn't the column change from tinytext to longtext when you remove the length property from a `text` type.